# If $L/k$ and $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=h(x)$ in $k[x]$, then $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ is also $h(x)$ in $L[x]$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to prove this theorem:

Let $L/k$ be field extension, and let $f(x),g(x)$ be two polynomials in $k[x]\setminus\{0\}$ and $h(x)=\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ in $k[x]$, then prove that the $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ is also $h(x)$ when $f(x),g(x)$ are considered as elements in $L[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x)=h(x)f^\ast(x)$ and $g(x)=h(x)g^\ast(x)$, where $f^\ast(x)$ and $g^\ast(x)$ are polynomials in $k[x]$, and $f^\ast(x)$ and $g^\ast(x)$ are relatively prime over $k[x]$.

It follows by Bezout's Theorem that there exist polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in $k[x]$ such that
$$a(x)f^\ast(x)+b(x)g^\ast(x)=1.$$
Thus $f^\ast(x)$ and $g^\ast(x)$ are relatively prime over $L[x]$, and therefore $h(x)$ is a greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over $L[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ gcds in Euclidean domains D persist in extension rings because the gcd may be specified by the solvability of (linear) equations over D,  and such solutions always persist in extension rings, i.e. roots in D remain roots in rings $\rm\,R \supset D.\:$ More precisely, the [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd yields the following ring-theoretic equational specification for the gcd

$$\rm\ gcd(a,b) = c\ \iff\ a\: \color{#C00}x = c,\  b\:\color{#C00} y = c,\,\ a\:\color{#C00} u + b\: \color{#C00}v = c\ \  has\ roots\ \ \color{#C00}{x,y,u,v}\in D$$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\:$ In any ring $\rm R,\:$  $\rm\:a\: x = c,\ b\: y = c\:$ have roots $\rm\:x,y\in R$ $\iff$ $\rm c\ |\ a,b\:$ in $\rm R.$ Further if $\rm\:c = a\: u + b\: v\:$ has roots $\rm\:u,v\in R\:$ then $\rm\:d\ |\ a,b$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:d\ |\ a\:u+b\:v = c\:$ in $\rm\: R.\:$ Hence we infer $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in $\rm\: R,\:$ being a common divisor divisible by every common divisor. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ If $\rm\:c = gcd(a,b)\:$ in D then the Bezout identity  implies the existence of such roots $\rm\:u,v\in D.\ $ **QED**

Rings with such linearly representable gcds are known as *Bezout* rings. As above, gcds in such rings always persist in extension rings. In particular, coprime elements remain coprime in extension rings (with same $1$). This need not be true without such Bezout linear representations of the gcd. For example, $\rm\:\gcd(2,x) = 1\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x]\:$ but the gcd is the nonunit  $\:2\:$ in $\rm\:\mathbb Z[x/2]\subset \mathbb Q[x]$.