# if $m$ and $n$ relatively prime integers different from $\pm 1$, there are unique integers $u$ , $v$ $\in Z$ such that $um+vn=1$ and $0 \le u \lt |n|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime integers different from $\pm 1$. Show that there are unique integers $u$ , $v$ $\in Z$ such that $um+vn=1$ and $0 \le u \lt |n|$. In this case show that $|v| \lt |m|$

My try: Let there be two such integers, $u$, $u'$, $v$ and $v'$.
Then $um+vn=1$ and $u'm+v'n=1$. Subtracting one from the other we get $m(u-u')+n(v-v')=0$. Now $m(u-u')=n(v'-v)$. Since $(m,n)=1$, we have $n | (u-u')$. Also $m |(v-v')$. There exists $k$ and $k'$ such that $u=u'+nk$ and $v=v'+mk'$.

From here how do I show the required??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: We need to show two things here, *existence* and *uniqueness*. The existence part does not seem to have been addressed. I do not know what can be assumed here, since the problem presumably arises in a certain course context. I would guess that it has already been proved that there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xm+yn=1$, and we are only asked to deal with size issues.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do i show existence??

Comment: I will assume you know there are $x_0,y_0$ such that $x_0m+ny_0=1$. Then for any $t$, we have $(x_0-tn)m+(y_0+tm)n=1$. By the Division Algorithm,  there is a $t$ such that $x_0-tn$ satisfies the desired inequalities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas got it

Comment: Good!  The uniqueness has been amply dealt with in the answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Now the new $x_0=x_0-tn$. But I also need to show that $|y_0+tm|\lt |m|$ simultaneously. How do I show it??

Comment: We don't need to use $t$ for the second part. If $0\lt u\lt |n|$, then $u|m|\lt |mn|$, so $u|m|-1\lt |mn|-1$. But $u|m|-1=-v|n|$, so $|vn|\lt |mn|-1$, which forces $|v|\lt |m|$.

Answer (score 1):

If $u,u'$ both satisfy $0 \le x < |n|$ then the absolute value of their difference is less than $|n|$. You have already arrived at $u=u'+nk$ so the absolute value of their difference is $|n||k|.$ So now what if $k\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ You've proved $\,u'\equiv u\pmod n.\,$ Therefore their remainders mod $\,n\,$ are equal. However, they *equal* their remainders mod $\,n\,$ since $\,0\le u',u < |n|.\,$ Therefore they are equal $\,u' = u.$

**Remark** $\ $ Such consequences of the *uniqueness* of the remainder in the Division Algorithm are ubiquitous in number theory and algebra, so it's very worthwhile to be familiar with this viewpoint. For example [here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/764515/242) one of my favorites.