# Euclidean Domain and Divison Algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In ED definition we need for all $a, b$ not zero then there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $a = bq+r$ with some condition with respect to norm.

Actually I am interested whether $q$ and $r$ are unique in ED or not

Further Questions:
1. Can we define some norm in ED with respect to which q and r are unique
   And in how many ways we can define such norms

2. If it is not possible what algebraic structure like this i.e. ED with uniqueness of q and  r, has some special properties.

Comment: Yes exactly because of uniqueness in k[x] i asked this question

Comment: Uniqueness holds only for fields $\,F\,$ and univariate polynomial rings over fields $\,F[x],\,$ see the links to papers of Jodeit and Rhai in [this answer,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/764515/242) which gives a nce application of such uniqueness.